# Clear IE cache C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, caching

I have a problem with Internet Explorer and cache (I think).

Easy explained, I'm trying to edit a user in my SQL database using LINQ-to-SQL, which works perfectly.
After the user is edited, it sends me back to a page I've made with a list of all users, and I can then click on any user I want to edit.

The problem is, if I then click on the same user I just edited, the changes haven't been done, but in the database, they have been changed, so I think there might be a problem with the IE cache or something.

Anyone knows if there is a way in Visual Studio to clear the IE cache for this specific page?
I know I can just press ctrl+F5, but I want it to update without having to press ctrl+F5.

Btw, my website is programmed in c# and .net 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to [refresh your data context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.refresh.aspx).

L2S doesn't 'cache', as such, but it sometimes needs prompting to refresh the data from the database, depending on how you've done your data update.

Comment: Okey, how do I refresh it?

Tried myDBDatacontext.Refresh, but that doesn't seems to exist.

Comment: Sorry without seeing the actual code it's hard to know. Your L2S data context should definitely have a refresh method (as per the link) assuming it's a System.Data.Linq.DataContext.

Comment: Problem solved, It was my Internet Explorer that had checked the "Never" on "Check for newer versions of stored pages" for some reason..

Answer (score 0):

You can try appending random number in the link of the user, like:

```
<a href="Page.aspx?userId=123&rnd={JUST A RANDOM NUMBER OR TICKS} />
```

This concept is the same as the JavaScript being cached, in the IIS it will have the same interpretation but will force to get the new one.

Comment: Problem solved, It was my Internet Explorer that had checked the "Never" on "Check for newer versions of stored pages" for some reason..